# How does one get a list of facebook campaign impressions and budget per campaign with ruby?

Tags: ruby, facebook-graph-api

I have the following code that returns a list of names of all campaigns that I have in my Facebook business manager account using [facebook-ruby-business-sdk](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ruby-business-sdk).

```
require 'facebookbusiness'
FacebookAds.configure do |config|
  config.access_token = '_____private_info______'
  config.app_secret = '_____private_info______'
end

ad_account = FacebookAds::AdAccount.get('act______private_info______', 'name')
puts "Ad Account Name: #{ad_account.name}"

# Printing all campaign names
ad_account.campaigns(fields: 'name').each do |campaign|
  puts campaign.name
end
```

The `campaign` object in the final loop is an instance of `FacebookAds::Campaign`.

Rather than just having a list of names, I also need budget and impressions for each campaign in the last month.

How do I need to change the code to get these results?

Comment: What does a `campaign` look like in your loop?

Comment: @SRack campaign in the loop looks like this: #<FacebookAds::Campaign:0x0000000_censored_>.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me as if you just need to select the fields and they'll be available in your loop:

```
ad_account.campaigns(fields: %w[name budget impressions]).each do |campaign|
  puts [campaign.name, campaign.budget, campaign.impressions].join(', ')
end
```

Does that work for you? Let me know how you get on or if you have any questions.

Comment: Thanks @SRack. However, this code yields: (#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (impressions) on node type (AdCampaignGroup)

Comment: How does one find out, which fields do exist in 'ad_account.campaigns'?

Comment: Use something like [pry](https://github.com/pry/pry) (pry is _great_), or look at the docs. Thought there was a chance the variables weren't named as simply, but this should do the job when you find out the available fields.